# How can I move the terminal?

Tags: raspbian, video, output

For some reason my TV is cutting off about 4 or 5 characters from the screen of my Raspberry Pi. I am using Raspbian, but it occurred with Arch as well.

Could it be that I have an HDMI to Component converter? Is there a way to adjust the terminal to the right?

Answer (score 3):

I expect that the issue is that your Raspberry Pi is using different resolution to your TV.

The resolution can be changed manually by editing the Raspberry Pi `config` file which is located at `/boot/config.txt`

You must enter an `hdmi_group` and `hdmi_mode` in that file in order to set the resolution. The values that correspond to the resolution you want can be found half way down [this wiki page](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tags/config.txt/info).

For example:

```
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=35
```

Would give you a resolution of `1280x1024` at `60Hz`

> **CEA:**
>
> Electronic Industries Alliance (EIA-861B) refers to a CEA/EIA standard
>   which consists of display timing and formats supported by Digital
>   Televisions
>
> **DMT:**
>
> Display Monitor Timings (DMT) are a list of VESA standard pre-defined
>   timings which are commonly used within the Computer industry.

This leads me to believe that CEA (`hdmi_group=1`) should be used for televisions. Whereas DMT (`hdmi_group=2`) should be for computer monitors.

Comment: Sorry about the delay. What's the difference between CEA and DMT?

Comment: @VinylScratch I'm not 100% sure, but I believe they are just different standards of specifying resolution. I'll add a note at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: In fact, I think I'll add that to the wiki.

Comment: I just found out that my boot folder is empty.

Comment: @VinylScratch: It's probably just not mounted. You'll need to mount `/dev/mmcblk0p1` to `/boot/`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to react almost 7 years later...
I believe this problem could be related and solved to overscan.

Either set your TV to display every pixels without cutting the border.
Or, on the Pi specify that some pixels are not visible and should not be used. And this can be done in /boot/config.txt

```
# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
#disable_overscan=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16
```